# Подключиться удаленно к базе данных?

Tags: windows, ms-access

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть программа, которая использует базу данных access. В программе нельзя управлять базой данной и как то подключать ее. База данных хранится локально в системной папке программы.

Вопрос как подключиться к базе данных, если я ее расшарю на сервере?

Comment: *как подключиться к базе данных, если я ее расшарю на сервере?* Изменить путь к файлу БД в настройках соединения с БД.

Comment: Ну если не заморачиваться с правами доступа, DFS и прочими радостями многоранговой сети, то каждому клиенту тиражировать программу. А затем прилинковать файл базы данных в каталог, например такой утилитой: **mklink myDB.mdb \\SERVER\Share\myDB.mdb** Но если мне не изменяет память, многопользовательский режим доступа к Access-файлу подразумевает создание в том же каталоге файла блокировок: .ldb. В общем, база должна быть готова к таком режиму.